# How to validate a Classic ASP form with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, asp-classic

Is it possible to get AngularJS working with Classic ASP? I couldn't find any resources on this, but I suspect the answer would be yes, since AngularJS (excluding its AJAX stuff) is mostly Client Side.

If that is the case, I have a form that looks like this:

[image: bootstrap form]

How can I use AngularJS to validate this form? The validation I want is:

- All Fields Required
- Email must be valid format

I know I can use jQuery, but I want to do this with AngularJS. I have already gone ahead and added the AngularJS script to the bottom of the form, also added the `ng-app` to the `<html` tag.

I'd like to know the proper, decoupled way of doing this, also if possible, client side end to end test for this simple form, just so that I get the idea.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to DoubleSharp's link, I have progressed a little, though validation still does not work.

Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-controller="UserCtrl">
  <form novalidate class="css-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.fname" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.lname" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript/Angular Code:

```
function UserCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.master= {};

    $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();
}
```

As you can see I simply copying [the tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), I have also gone ahead and added the CSS styles, but my validation is still not working, even though the page is freshly loaded, I get `ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required` CSS on my text fields, whereas in the tutorial they have `ng-valid`

I am guessing this has something to do with `ngModel` which I have no where, but the tutorial does not mention that at all in its code, I'm confused.

Comment: `angularjs` is a framework. it makes no sense to use it to just to validate a form. you design a webapp from the ground up using `angularjs`, you don't plug angularjs into one particular functionality of one page of your app. Also not sure why you added the `twitter-bootstrap` tag here, has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Hmmmm, ASP=server-side, AngularJS=client-side, no problem here.  Doesn't matter what AngularJS talks to on the server, just as it doesn't matter what jQuery or Vanilla JS would talk to.  I think you answered your own question.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Aye it makes no sense now, I'm just begining with it, later I will use the beast as was intended :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to validate that the required fields are entered and that the email is in a valid format, it can all be done client side without any calls back to the server, so it doesn't matter if it is ASP classic, PHP, etc... it is all in the browser. The AngularJS site has examples of this, so rather than repeating them here...

See this page for implementing custom form validation: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

See this page for the email input type: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.email

Comment: Thanks DoubleSharp, I attempting following the tutorial, but still not working. See updated Q.